# css- how to add dynamic slider to image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a dynamic layout that retrieves picture from my `banner` table and display on the view page. I already set up the model and controller on my laravel project. It looks something like below:

[image]

It retrieves the 2 pictures but stack it one below another. I would wonder if there is a way I can make it as a slider,i.e the 1st picture will slider to the left/right and changes to the 2nd picture automatically, so on and so forth.

My code:

```
<!-- Banner Area Start -->
  <section class="hero-area">

        <div class="hero-area-slider">

          <!--class for display banner -->
          <div class="intro-carousel">
            @foreach($data as $pic)
              <div class="intro-content" style="background-image: url({{asset('/images/'.$pic->photo)}})">
                <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                      <div class="slider-content">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>

          </div>
              @endforeach
        </div>     
  </section>
  <br>
```

Style:

```
/*-----------------------------
** Banner Area Start
------------------------------*/



.hero-area .hero-area-slider .intro-carousel .intro-content {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 500px;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-position: center !important;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;

  margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
  }
  .hero-area .hero-area-slider .intro-carousel .intro-content.slide-one {
    text-align: left; }
  .hero-area .hero-area-slider .intro-carousel .intro-content.slide-two {
    text-align: center; }
  .hero-area .hero-area-slider .intro-carousel .intro-content.slide-three {
    text-align: right; }

    .hero-area .hero-area-slider .intro-carousel .intro-content .slider-content .layer-1 .subtitle {
      font-size: 24px;
      font-weight: 700;
      color: #143250;
       }
    .hero-area .hero-area-slider .intro-carousel .intro-content .slider-content .layer-1 .title {
      font-size: 36px;
      font-weight: 700;
      color: #ff5500;
       }

    .hero-area .hero-area-slider .intro-carousel .intro-content .slider-content .layer-2 .text {
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 600;
      color: #143250;
      max-width: 400px;
      display: inline-block; }

    .hero-area .hero-area-slider .intro-carousel .intro-content .slider-content .layer-3 a {
      margin-top: 15px;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid #ff5500;
    }
    .hero-area .hero-area-slider .intro-carousel .intro-content .slider-content .layer-3 a:hover {
      background: #fff;
      color: #ff5500;
    }

    .hero-area .hero-area-slider .intro-carousel .intro-content .slider-content .layer-3 a i{
  font-size: 13px;}


/* hero Slider dot design Start */

.hero-area .hero-area-slider .owl-controls .owl-dots {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: 20px;
}
  .hero-area .hero-area-slider .owl-controls .owl-dots .owl-dot {
    width: 25px;
    height: 6px;
    background: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 0px;
    transform: skewX(-30deg);
    margin: 0px 3px 0px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-in;
    -o-transition: 0.3s ease-in;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
    .hero-area .hero-area-slider .owl-controls .owl-dots .owl-dot.active {
      background: #fff;
      width: 50px
    }

    .blog-area .aside .slider-wrapper .owl-controls .owl-dots {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: -1px; }
      .blog-area .aside .slider-wrapper .owl-controls .owl-dots .owl-dot {
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        background: #c2c2c2;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin: 0px 3px 0px;
        -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in;
        -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-in;
        -o-transition: 0.3s ease-in;
        transition: 0.3s ease-in; }
        .blog-area .aside .slider-wrapper .owl-controls .owl-dots .owl-dot.active {
          background: #ff5500;
          -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
          -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
          transform: scale(1.2); }
```

I wonder if I can add slider where I can also use my mouse and clik/drag left or right so it changes picture. Thanks

Comment: You can use slick slider: https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: is the setup complicated?

Comment: No, just add css and js of slick slider, check codepen demo: https://codepen.io/MaggieSadler/pen/NGvrNq

Comment: And I have to change content of my html? Sorry as I have not used third party libraries laravel before.

Comment: Oh, I checked out your codepen but I want to stick to my size and width and other settings on my code. Just add in the feature for sliding

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <!-- ad your picture url between the " " quotes -->
  <img src=" " style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Picture 1</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <!-- ad your picture url between the " " quotes -->
  <img src=" " style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Picture 2</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <!-- ad your picture url between the " " quotes -->
  <img src=" " style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Picture 3</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So I have to change everything?